Google Calendar API why is EXDATE not working
I want to add an event to a google calendar. Here is the request data :
{
  'summary': 'Test', 
  'start': {
    'dateTime': '2024-08-26T13:00:00-04:00', 
    'timeZone': 'America/Montreal'
  }, 
  'end': {
    'dateTime': '2024-08-26T13:30:00-04:00', 
    'timeZone': 'America/Montreal'
  }, 
  'reminders': {
    'useDefault': False, 
    'overrides': [
      {
        'method': 'popup', 
        'minutes': 30
      }
    ]
  }, 
  'recurrence': [
    'RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;UNTIL=20250610T235959Z',
    'EXDATE;TZID=America/Montreal:20240831T130000Z,20240901T130000Z,20240902T130000Z'
  ]
}

But when I check the Google Calendar, the recurrence is applied but the dates listed as EXDATE are not respected. I'm not sure why.
I also tried using RDATE but there was issues with the Daylight saving time.
Does anyone has an idea of what's wrong?

I believe Z at the end of the iso formatted datetime indicates UTC timezone. While you're using America/Montreal. That might cause an issue. Try removing Zs from EXDATE datetimes.

That was exactly the problem! Thank you!
